# Why is this if scope in my function completely ignored by the javascript interpreter?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, undefined

I have a function to practically create an HTML element and bind it quickly.

However it does not work as it should.

When I use debug(ggCreateElement), I see that it skips the `if` scope entirely even if the statement is "true". I've run out of ideas.

```
function ggCreateElement(tagName,className,idName,appendPointTagName) {
    d=document.createElement(tagName);
    d.className=className;
    d.id=idName;
    ap=document.getElementsByTagName(appendPointTagName);
        if (ap.lenght==0) {
           console.log("Append point tag name is not found ! ") ;
        }
        else {
           ap[0].appendChild(d);
           return d;
    }
}
```

Could you help me out please? Thank you.

Comment: How do you invoke it ?

Comment: `ap.lenght`? are you pasting the right code? also `console.log(ap.length);` before the if block

Comment: What is the value of `ap.lenght` when you debug and is this typo deliberate?

Comment: Looks like a type in `ap.lenght`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code works fine and returns proper element once you change your typo in the if condition from

```
if (ap.lenght==0)
```

to

```
if (ap.length==0)
```

Aditionally you might as well do

```
if (!ap.length)
```